# Can Peiels-Bogoliubov inequality be extended to infinite-dimensions?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

I am interested in trace inequalities and especially the Peierls-Bogoliubov inequality. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#cite_note-C09-1) has some information and references on the subject, but as far as I've checked, the proofs are restricted to finie-dimensions (matrices). I was wondering if there are any references that prove the Peierls-Bogoliubov inequality for operators on an infinite-dim Hilbert space?